# A simpler, more efficient way to remove duplicate rows from an SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

**Overview**
I have a table (EODBalances) in SQL Server 2008 R2 that has a significant # of rows (~ 200 million). Essentially it is in an accounting system (general ledger) and its role is to store the closing balance for each and every account in the accounting system.

**The table definition**

```
[EodBalances](
[EodBalanceId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Balance] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL
```

**The task**
The # of accounts is growing exponentially and hence causing the # of rows in the EODBalances table to grow similarly. Apart from the exponential growth one of the existing issues is that we add a new row for every account every day even when there is no change to the account balance. My task is to reduce the # of rows in this table by removing duplicate rows for each account. I have refactored the stored proc that updates this table every night so that it will only add a new row if the balance has changed. This is of course will only occur going forward.

**The problem**
The task I am having challenges on is the cleanup of the historical rows in the table which is a specific type of problem to do with duplicate removal.  I need to keep the original (first) entry of any account balance in the table but remove any subsequent rows where the closing balance doesn't change. As soon as it changes I need to keep that specific row and then again remove subsequent rows until it changes again. And so on...

I have tried a few different ways to achieve this but all of them are very inefficient and in addition to the time they take to run, have side effects like massive log files (which are a pain when the database is log shipped). the current solution I have is to create a copy of the table and copy out the rows I want to keep into the copy and delete them from the original table. Once this is done then I delete the original table and rename the copy back to the original name. This works but take more hours than I have in the upgrade window available.

Has anyone had a similar issue and found a better way to deal with it?

Comment: Removing rows from huge table is very time consuming. I don't know have you tried using partitioning. If not, I suggest you partition your table in a proper way and then work on each different partition  to update and delete data. you need to use partition switching techniques. search for it

Comment: Good idea for future 're-design' work - but I recently discovered partitioning is only available in Enterprise SQL*Server and not all of us are blessed with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s an outline of a process I’ve come up with for similar situations:

- Devise an algorithm to identify the duplicated rows to be deleted. Use group by, min(), max(), row_number(), whatever, there are several ways of doing this, they’ve all been posted in SO many times, and it sounds like you’ve got one already.
- As you have noted, this is a big chunk of work to do.
- Split the big chunk of work into pieces, and work on one chunk at a time. Spread this work out over time, to keep your transaction log size under control. If (say) you do t-log backups every hour, run this process only a few times an hour, to keep the transaction log small and the t-log backup files not too out of hand.
- How to split it up? Based on your data, I’d say by AccountId. Process a number (1, 10, 100, 1000?) in each batch, whatever size is reasonable for your conditions (ref. transaction log bloat above).
- How to manage all this? Create a “purge log” table. Populate it with all AccountId that need to be checked (i.e. you don’t have to add new accounts to it). Do some form of looping, where you run the Delete routine once per account, or once per 10 accounts, or whatever. Once purged, mark the account in the purge log table as “has been processed”, and don’t process it again. Log how many rows were deleted and when the work was done, so you can keep track of progress.

  - Last step is scheduling. Make it all a stored procedure, and configure a SQL agent job to call this procedure ever X times a (t-log backup cycle). Schedule it to run during viable windows—all day long if it’s “non-invasive”, or Sunday AM hours if that’s when the system is clear enough. (I’ve got one running now for 16 hours on the weekend, between the “last” differential backup and the weekly complete backup.)
- Let it run until the work is done. If the work has to be done ASAP, concessions may have to be paid to log sizes, performance during business hours, and whatever else.

Comment: @FLICKER's comment applies too, but setting up table partitioning is very non-trivial and seems impractical given your current status (in Production, in use, and suffering).

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new table for this and then reload the data.  Identifying the row is not that hard.  You need to identify groups.  It goes something like this:

```
select e.*,
       row_number() over (partition by AccountId, balance, grp order by created) as seqnum
from (select e.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by AccountId order by created) -
              row_number() over (partition by AccountId, balance order by created)
             ) as grp
      from EODBalances e
     ) e;
```

The rows with the seqnum go first.

Then I would do something like this:

```
select *
into temp_EODBalances
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by AccountId, balance, grp order by created) as seqnum
      from (select e.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by AccountId order by created) - 
                    row_number() over (partition by AccountId, balance order by created)
                   ) as grp
            from EODBalances e
           ) e
      ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Then, I would test "the hell" out of the table.  Finally, when satisfied (and after having backed up the original table), I would do:

```
truncate table EODBalances;

insert into EODBalances(. . . )
    select . . .
    from temp_EODBalances;
```

Comment: I was about to comment that I believe the most efficient way to do this is as a windowing SQL statement (using the OVER syntax) - exactly as you've done in full detail above.  Provided Hamish has the necessary time window and storage space to (almost) replicate this huge table (and deal with the logs generated)  then I can't see a better way than this (given my limited knowledge).  If he doesn't, then I agree with Philip below that doing it in chunks over many windows of time is a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried running your suggested t-sql on a copy of live on my local machine but it fails due to running out of memory.